# RestAssured vs Postman automation Test in RESTful service

Tags: testing, automation

I tried writing tests in postman to validate the response in postman. Want to know what are all the limitations in postman testing and how it is compared to Rest Assured.

Answer (score 11):

**Postman** :
*Advantages:*

1. Easy to use, hence quick to learn.
2. Can be used for
3. Manual/Exploratory as well as Automation Testing. Easy to integrate
   in CI.

*Disadvantages :*

4. Cannot customize reporting.
5. Each collection can be provided with only 1 data file. Hence limitations when designing data driven automation framework.

**Rest Assured:**
*Advantages :*

1. Provides DSL so that the test are Behaviour driven.
2. Java Library,hence the automation suite can be designed such that code can be reusable.
3. More the reusability, Lesser is the maintainence cost.
4. Can be used with any customised/open source reporting tool.
5. No limitations while designing data-driven automation framework design.
   Can use excel or csv as data provider.

Comment: Postman has surely evolved and now you can generate custom reports as well as use CSV files for data driven automation

Comment: A further downside of postman is a horrible developer experience in terms of handling collections in git...Collections need to be imported and exported with every change, and code reviewing (and conflict solving) of huge json files is a pain compared to regular source code.